# Step7 - How to call cyclic interruptions

Tags: logic, plc

I would like to call cyclic interruption from OB1 and I would like to generate the duration time of that interruption. I know that I can put some kind of counter / timer into a FB and somehow generate the value of that timer. However I do not know how to execute this in a loop so I do not have to press buttons or switches.

Thank you.

EDIT:
I am considering myself as a PLC beginner. :)

I am not going to work with real SIMATIC station at first so I will be using PLCSIM to test my application(program). By cyclic interruption I mean something like OB30 - OB38.

It should work like this:

1. I will set my input to "Logical 1", which will initialize loop. (I am not sure if this is necessary)
2. Now a very simple program will be executing (settiing /resetting coil) in a loop - this is just a example and it does not matter what the program will be doing right now.
3. Somewhere during execution a interruption will occur. I think it may be a function in which I will set up a timer with randomly generated value of duration.
4. After / during the function execution (from "3."), I need to save the generated value in DB.
5. Now "2." to "4." should be executed in a "never ending" loop until I set the input from the "1." to logical 0.

Comment: Your question hasn't got enough context for others to answer it. You need to explain what kind of PLC you are using, what a "cyclic interruption is" (I consider myself a PLC expert but have no clue what that is), or why you want it.

Comment: @IraBaxter Thanks for comment. Take a look to my edit please.

Answer (score 1):

Interrupts can not be called from OB1. There only cyclic, fault and hardware interrupts available.
Use a FC or an FB that is being called when a timer is ready by making the enable input of this function call/block high. It will not directly being called like an interrupt, but fast enough.

I think you're confusing a PLC with a micorcontroller.
Why do you need code executed directly when there is an input high? Is this a safety demand or something with motion?

Comment: Since I am a beginner with Step7 and PLC, I do not reallz know what do you mean by "input hight" :). As I mention above, I would like to generate duration length of that timer. I am going to examine how to deal with random events in a complex system. However I need to learn the basics first :)

Comment: Input high, my mistake. Just that you make a marker or input to 1.

Comment: Input high, my mistake. Just that you make a marker or input to 1.
If you want to measure an interrupt, you could start a timer in the interrupt and end in the last network. It is not a good plan to do more tasks in an interrupt than necessary.
Basically you don't need this information in a running environment.  
So, I am still curious why you need to know the execution time of an interrupt? I think that the real problem has a different answer.

Answer (score 1):

I got here looking for something similar.
Since I couldn't find what I needed I just risk it and tried it on a running plant. Good thing is nothing blew, so everything fine.

Now, simple answer:

- Cyclic interrupts are configured on the hardware config of S7.
- I used OB35 for my purposes which was to create a 1ms resolution time count.(CPU 315 timer resolution only goes to 10ms)
- In hardware config double click CPU then cyclic interrupts and set the time under execution to 1(1 milisecond, this is my case yours could be different).
- Then I created a basic rudimentary timer, just what I needed and nothing extra since I've seen on Siemens portal that within this time resolution CPU stop may occur if too much code on OB35.
- Finally, first rung on OB35 is an 'add' 1 instruction to a temp variable, second is to reset when a given number of ms is reached.
- If you need to add execution condition then just put an enable bit on the first rung and you will stop the count.

Be aware that OB35 doesn't need to be 'called' CPU will call it for you at the selected interval(set under hardware config)

regards

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the cyclic interrupts are called by the PLC itself at a pre spcified interval (or by using a hardware interrupt). That is not something you can call by using a timer in your program (as I understood your question).

If I got this right you want to run a loop continuosly and every now and then interrupt the loop to generate some data and then store that data before the loop ends.

In that case may I suggest that you include the data genereting and storing code into your loop? You can use the same trigger that you were planning in this case too. You simply use it to jump past the code that does the data genereation/storing bit when it is not active.

At most you will loose a couple of MS worth of time here compared to doing a real interrupt, if that is unacceptable in some way maybe you should consider another type of device instead of a PLC.